# Trying to create speaker recognition Neural Network but unfortunetlly my NN have very low accucary

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, speech-recognition, mfcc

Im trying to create an speaker recognition system which take sound files from any movie and than train these sounds files using Neural Network and MFCC ( sound feature ) and then the system will say me on another sound file which speaker talked in this sound file.

***So that's what I did -***

1. Created MFCC vector for each speaker and put it on an array named X ( speaker can be more than one time )
2. Created Output number for each speaker
3. Created this model with tensorflow -

   1. Dense Layer(512, 'relu')
   2. Dropout    (0.3)
   3. Dense Layer(256, 'relu')
   4. Dense Layer(128, 'relu')
   5. Flattern
   6. Dense Layer(length of outputs, 'relu')

than I trained and finally checked my results but as I said unfortuentlly my results are not high enough, only ~45% accucarry :(

I add my full code and my data base, notice that my data base can make some mistakes for example take voice of leonard and call it sheldon because it base on the srt file of the movie and the srt file have sometimes mistakes.

***My Full Code :***

```
import python_speech_features
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
import os
import shutil
from os.path import isfile, join
from random import shuffle
from matplotlib import pyplot
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
win_len = 0.04  # in seconds
step = win_len / 2
nfft = 2048
for TestNum in tqdm(range(5)):  # We check it several times
    X = []  # inputs
    Y = []  # outputs
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("FinalAudios/") if isfile(join("FinalAudios/", f))]   # Files in dir
    names = []  # names of the speakers
    for file in onlyfiles:  # for each wav sound
        # UNESSECERY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE
        if " " not in file.split("_")[0]:
            names.append(file.split("_")[0])
        else:
            names.append(file.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0])
    only_speakers = [] + names
    namesWithoutDuplicate = list(dict.fromkeys(names))
    namesWithoutDuplicateCopy = namesWithoutDuplicate[:]
    for name in namesWithoutDuplicateCopy:  # we remove low samples files
        if names.count(name) < 60:
            namesWithoutDuplicate.remove(name)
    names = namesWithoutDuplicate
    print(names)  # print it
    vector_names = []  # output for each name
    i = 0
    for name in names:
        vector_for_each_name = i
        vector_names.append(np.array(vector_for_each_name))
        i += 1
    for f in onlyfiles:  # for all the files
        if " " not in f.split("_")[0]:
            f_speaker = f.split("_")[0]
        else:
            f_speaker = f.split("_")[0].split(" ")[0]
        if f_speaker in namesWithoutDuplicate:
            fs, audio = wav.read("FinalAudios/" + f)  # read the file
            try:
                # compute MFCC
                mfcc_feat = python_speech_features.mfcc(audio, samplerate=fs, winlen=win_len,
                                                   winstep=step, nfft=nfft, appendEnergy=False)
                flat_list = [item for sublist in mfcc_feat for item in sublist]
                # Create output + inputs
                X.append(np.array(flat_list))
                Y.append(np.array(vector_names[names.index(f_speaker)]))
            except IndexError:
                pass
        else:
            if not os.path.exists("TooLowSamples"):  # if path not exist we create it
                os.makedirs("TooLowSamples")
            shutil.move("FinalAudios\\" + f, "TooLowSamples\\" + f)
    # ------------------- RANDOMIZATION, UNNECESSARY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE ------------------- #
    Z = list(zip(X, Y))
    shuffle(Z)  # WE SHUFFLE X,Y TO PERFORM RANDOM ON THE TEST LEVEL
    X, Y = zip(*Z)
    X = list(X)
    Y = list(Y)
    lenX = len(X)
    # ------------------- RANDOMIZATION, UNNECESSARY TO UNDERSTAND THE CODE ------------------- #
    y_test = np.asarray(Y[:100])   # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    x_test = np.asarray(X[:100])   # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    x_train = np.asarray(X[100:])  # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    y_train = np.asarray(Y[100:])  # CHOOSE 100 FOR TEST, OTHERS FOR TRAIN
    x_val = x_train[-100:]         # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    y_val = y_train[-100:]         # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    x_train = x_train[:-100]       # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    y_train = y_train[:-100]       # FROM THE TRAIN CHOOSE 100 FOR VALIDATION
    x_train = x_train.reshape(np.append(x_train.shape, 1))  # RESHAPE FOR INPUT
    x_test = x_test.reshape(np.append(x_test.shape, 1))     # RESHAPE FOR INPUT
    x_val = x_val.reshape(np.append(x_val.shape, 1))        # RESHAPE FOR INPUT

    # -------------- OUR TENSOR FLOW NEURAL NETWORK MODEL -------------- #
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(names), activation='softmax'),
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    # -------------- OUR TENSOR FLOW NEURAL NETWORK MODEL -------------- #

    print("fitting")
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=4, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
    print("testing")
    results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    print(results)
    pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
    pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.show()
```

My data set - https://filebin.net/ajho6kgzx66xayyn

Note : I tried also convolution layers but it worked even worse

Comment: Your problem is not the code (I haven't even looked at it tbh) but it is definitely in your training data. How much is it? How many speakers you have? How the annotations have been done? If you want to train a proper speaker indipendent ASR you would need more than 100h of properly annotated speech.

Comment: I have about 1200 sound files of 1 second each all this for  4 speakers meaning 300 seconds for each speaker which i understand from your comment that is really low :( @lCapp